# Query String Parsing - Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, query-string, google-tag-manager, text-parsing, string-parsing

I have a custom javascript variable created in Google Tag Manager which is supposed to parse out certain parameters from the query string, but it doesn't seem to be working entirely as intended. The script fails to parse out a certain set of parameters.

For example, the script does not parse out "name" from the following, but it manages to parse out "email" just fine. http://halfdayfactor.com/inactive/10.php?name=testin&email=testing15490%40gmail.com

The script works when I try it in a regular browser. It parses out everything listed in the initial array properly, but it doesn't seem to work in Google Tag Manager, and I have no idea why. I've tried switching the order of the params in the query string as well as the array to see if that has any effect, but to no avail. I really have no clue why this might be happening. Any insight is appreciated.

Here is a version of the code I adapted from this page: http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/04/17/strip-query-parameters-google-analytics/

```
function() {



 var params = ['payer_email','first_name','last_name','option_selection2','cname','cemail','czip','email','login',' from','token',' param','emailaddress','creditcards_name','address_street','street_number','phone','ipaddress','name','email'];
var _page = {{Page Path}};
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a = _page;

  if (a.search) {

var qps = a.search.replace('?', '&');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {

  var _param = params[i];
  var regex = new RegExp('&' + _param + '=[^&]*(&|$)', 'gi');
  qps = qps.replace(regex, '&')

}
qps[0] === '&' ? qps = qps.slice(1) : '';
a.search = qps;


  }

  return a;

}
```

Here is a version of the code I wrote myself to try and solve the problem and try out in a regular browser.

```
var params = ['payer_email','first_name','last_name','option_selection2','cname','cemail','czip','email','login','from','token','param','emailaddress','creditcards_name','address_street','street_number','phone','ipaddress','name','email'];
var qs = window.location.search;


var modqs = qs.replace('?', '&');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {

  var param = params[i];
  var regex = new RegExp('&' + param + '=[^&]*(&|$)', 'gi');
  modqs = modqs.replace(regex, '&');
}

var path = window.location.pathname;
modqs = modqs.substr(1);
document.write(path + '?' + modqs);
```

Comment: Do you want to avoid to create a lot of individual variables ? Else it would be more reliable to use the url type variables, set component type to "query" and specify the parameter name.

Comment: I just executed your code in my console on Chrome 54 and it does not parse out email as you said. My result is "/inactive/10.php?". What output are you expecting?

Comment: @Eike Pierstrorff, can you please explain another way. I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: @Matus Try the new code I pasted in the original post. The first version was something I had modded and may have had errors. The new code I have pasted in my original question is something I adapted from here, which might be more reliable: http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/04/17/strip-query-parameters-google-analytics/  I am trying to output a new query string which contains the original query string - the params that are listed in the "params" array.

Comment: I think you are doing the exact opposite of what you want to do. The new query string will contain all parameters BUT the ones you have listed in your array "params"

Comment: There is a URL variable in GTM and you can use it to parse query parameters but you will have to make a new variable for each parameter.